# Not able to read cookie in Angular.js from REST response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to read cookie from response of REST web service in angualr JS.
My application is calling below service.
http://127.0.0.1:29070/webbrokerproxy/wbservice/secure/basket/wbrokere

This returns response header as follows.

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, content-disposition,Content-Transfer-Encoding,X-WBAuthentication,Cache-Control,Pragma,If-Modified-Since,REMOTE_USER

Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Access-Control-Expose-Headers:X-WBAuthentication,REMOTE_USER

Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000

Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8

Date:Wed, 11 Apr 2018 08:07:17 GMT
Set-Cookie:authUser=wbrokere; path=/

Set-Cookie:_WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONID=Jfh3J6GzwYBFHgcIBUNy; path=/; secure; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=MxizvqlB2GtIXyfZ-HO4PbLH4cxId20pL4DyHw2XFfB58SLgwe0u!54246601; path=/; HttpOnly

Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=PTxQhNCVnVmNQ9Z8yWbp3TTcbsQTT4l0W9hwz0jVl2SvQDYYMkLm!-1045388091; path=/; HttpOnly

Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1

From angualr js code I am trying to read authUser cookie but I am getting value as undefined.

```
  WBTokenGenerator().get({}, function(response, header) {

        alert("auth user " + $cookies.get('authUser'));
        sessionStorage.wbtoken = response.token;

    },
```

Can any one explain why I am not able to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$cookies.get` will read the cookies that were set for *the current page at the time it was loaded*.

If you make an Ajax request, then the response might update the cookies stored in the browser, but it won't change history to rewrite the cookies that were set when you originally loaded the page.

There is no way to read the cookies from an Ajax response. You can't even [read the headers directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders) as `Set-Cookie` and  `Set-Cookie2` are explicitly inaccessible to JavaScript on the client.

---

That said, you should not need to read the cookie value explicitly. Any normal use of it would be handled transparently by the browser. You just need to make another HTTP request to a URL for which the cookie is set and it will be included in the request headers.

Comment: so if i want to save data locally returned by cookie how I should do it

Comment: You can't. That isn't what cookies are designed to do.

Comment: Whatever data you are getting or want to get should be in your response (body) and then if you want to save them, you can either use local storage or session storage (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) If you find this is not working for you, you are probably using cookies wrong.